# aiohttp server handler отправить параллельные http запросы

Tags: сервер, http, asyncio, aiohttp

Как одновременно отправить несколько параллельных асинхронных HTTP запросов в Handler-e aiohttp сервера ? Например в чистом asyncio, это примерно выглядело бы так , а в aiohttp ?

```
 import asyncio

 tasks = []

 async def simultanioslyreq():
     tasks.append(request1)
     tasks.append(request2)
     await asynаcio.wait(tasks)


 async def request1(url):
     return await asyncreq(url)

 async def request2(url):
      return await asyncreq(url)

 loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
 loop.run_until_complete(simultanioslyreq)
 loop.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aiohttp работает поверх asyncio, ничто не мешает вам использовать те же методы:

```
async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()


async def handle(request):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        urls = [
            'http://python.org',
            'https://pypi.org/'
        ]
        await asyncio.wait([fetch(session, url) for url in urls])
    return web.Response(text='Done')


app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get('/', handle)])

web.run_app(app)
```